# Create Excel binary in SQL server from an SQL SELECT query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel

While I am well aware of how to create Excel files from SQL server, this particular requirement is to create BINARIES, without ever saving to a file system.

Pseudo Code something like this:

```
DECLARE @ExcelBinaryData varbinary(max)
SELECT * FROM someTable FOR EXPORT to @ExcelBinaryData
```

I want this binary to then be returned to a C# application for download.

Appreciate solutions where it does NOT require saving files to the server.  I am aware of how to save a file and then read the binary.  But this requirement is to do it WITHOUT any writes to the file system.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Once you select your binary data from database, add it to response.
Something like this:

```
string connectionString = "your connection string";
int id = 1;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [ExcelData] FROM [SavedFiles] WHERE ID = @ID";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
    byte[] bytes = (byte[])dr["ExcelData"];
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", @"attachment;filename=""file.xlsx""");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.End();
}
```

bear in mind that this is not the complete solution, just a hint (and I didn't have time to test it).

Comment: Yes, easy enough when you have the binaries saved in Excel.  As per the above, I have a SELECT statement such as "SELECT name, surname FROM users" which I want to save to an Excel binary and return to my C# app.  I use HTTPMessaging to send Binary, MIME type, an filename to the browser.  What  am missing is the Excel binary that needs to be created from scratch.

Comment: that is not so simple. Google for NPOI library and you will find library for creating Excel files. And, I i remember correctly, you will have to save created excel to file system...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just in case anyone else needs to do this, I have settled for a compromise, using OLE DB and ACE drivers to write to Excel temporary file, and then send to SQL.  The Excel file manipulation is as follows.

PS: If you are like me writing code for major clients, we tend to avoid libraries written by randoms that might introduce security holes into the system.  This code uses MS libraries and no other external sources.

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;c:\\someFile.xlsx";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\"";
     using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [table1] (id INT, name VARCHAR, datecol DATE );";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table1](id,name,datecol) VALUES(1,'AAAA','2014-01-01');";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table1](id,name,datecol) VALUES(2, 'BBBB','2014-01-03');";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table1](id,name,datecol) VALUES(3, 'CCCC','2014-01-03');";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [table1] SET name = 'DDDD' WHERE id = 3;";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();
            }
```